# Show-Listview shows Item Id instead of Field Id

Tags: powershell-extensions

We're using Sitecore PowerShell Extensions to generate some reports.
In one of our templates we have a field with the name `Id`.
This `id` field is not being listed correctly by PSE because it is conflicting with the Item Id from Sitecore. How would we get our own `id` field in PSE instead of the Sitecore ID?

This is the shortened code.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $root -Language * | Show-ListView -Property Id,Description
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the "[Name/Expression scheme"](https://sitecorepowershell.gitbooks.io/sitecore-powershell-extensions/content/appendix/commands/Show-ListView.html#example-2) I was able to retrieve the field just like in C#. This gets the correct field value.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $root -Language * | Show-ListView -Property `
                 @{Label="Id"; Expression={$_.Fields["Id"].Value}}
```